# Java Individual ActionListeners and an Overarching ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way. Let me know
Using Swing and AWT, I have several buttons set up on a frame and they each have an ActionListener corresponding to their specific function I.E.

```
JButton foo_button = new JButton("Foo-Me");
foo_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //Fancy schmancy code work
    } 
})
JButton bar_button = new JButton("Bar None");
bar_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //Fancy schmancy code work
    } 
})
```

So each of these buttons do their own thing. However, what if I want all the buttons to do a certain thing (the same exact method for each), in my case, clear a label, before they do their own thing.

Obviously I could add whatever_label.setText("") to each actionPerformed() but that entails a lot of duplication, something I'm not so much a fan of.

Oh Java and Swing gurus come to my aid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subclass your own implementation of `ActionListener`:

```
private static abstract class MyListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    final public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        theSameTask();
        uniqueTask(evt);
    } 
    private void theSameTask() {
        // the identical task
    }
    public abstract void uniqueTask(ActionEvent evt);
}
```

And then, the new listeners will look like this:

```
JButton bar_button = new JButton("Bar None");
bar_button.addActionListener(new MyListener() {
    @Override public void uniqueTask(ActionEvent evt) {
        //Fancy schmancy code work
    } 
});
```

Comment: +1. No need to make a private method final though: it's implicitely final.

Comment: Could I put this inside the same file I am working in. It's for school and God forbid good coding apply. (we can only submit one file).

Comment: Just answered my own question. I'll definitely try this tomorrow. You get bonus points for including //Fancy schmancy code work

Comment: No problem if you can only submit one file ... just submit the resulting jar file, containing as many individual classes as you actually need :-) . Stupid rules just ask for creative workarounds

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use the ['Decorater' pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), and write an `ActionListener` decorator for the common behavior. Your code would then be of the form

```
bar_button.addActionListener(new MyActionListenerDecorator( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //Fancy schmancy code work
    }  }) );
```

Comment: I might try this one too. I've read about it before (Thank you Head First books). Good use of a great pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this is to use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). That way all the listeners always do the same thing.

Comment: 1,234 rep, are you _sure_ you want to be answering questions? :P

Comment: @Jacob Raihle wrote `1,234 rep, are you sure you want to be answering questions?`, I'm wrote ---> be sure that he want, he can, his answer is practically correct, covering most efficient of ways and from answers here too, everything depends of your knowledges about Java, Swing and theirs methods implemented in the API

Comment: @mKorbel I didn't mean any offense at all, only that it was a nice number to have :)

Comment: @@Jacob Raihle and I'd be use [EventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html) exclusivelly, sure ActionListener is common, easy and simple

Comment: @Jacob Raihle  I'm killed his nice numbers order:-) :-) :-) :-) :-)